# GNU Octave dimensions mismatch error?

Tags: matlab, octave, gnu

I take an error on GNU Octave.

```
error: sim_encryption: A(I,J,...) = X: dimensions mismatch
error: called from
    sim_encryption at line 11 column 13
Line 11 is "    s( 1 , : )  =  mod( s + k , 2 ) ;" .
```

When I search about error, it is said that the problem is about matrix, but matrixes are not look different. So what is the problem ?

```
ph  =  '3243f6a8885a308d313198a2e0370734' ;
kh  =  '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c' ;

k  =  zeros( 11 , 128 ) ;
r  =  zeros( 11 , 8 ) ;
s  =  zeros( 11 , 128 ) ;

s( 1 , : )  =  hex_to_bin( ph ) ;
k( 1 , : )  =  hex_to_bin( kh ) ;
r( 1 , : )  =  [ 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 ] ;
s( 1 , : )  =  mod( s + k , 2 ) ;

for  i  =  1  :  10 ,
    i ;
    [ k( i+1 , : ) , r( i+1 , : ) ]  =  key_schedule( k( i , : ) , r( i , : ) ) ;
    s( i+1 , : )  =  mod( k( i+1 , : ) + aes_round( s( i , : ) , i ) , 2 ) ;
    kh  =  bin_to_hex( k(i+1,:) , 32 ) ;
    sh  =  bin_to_hex( s(i+1,:) , 32 ) ;
end

ch  =  bin_to_hex( s(11,:) , 32 )
```

Comment: is the problem with `s( 1 , : )  =  hex_to_bin( ph ) ;` ?

Comment: No. with the  `s( 1 , : )  =  mod( s + k , 2 ) ;`

Comment: I think `mod(x,y)` is a 1x1 matrix and `s(1,:)` is a 1xn matrix that's why you're having a mismatch.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler why would `mod` return a scalar when passed an array input?

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't notice that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `s` and `k` are both of size 11 x 128, the result of
 `mod(s + k, 2)` is also 11 x 128 and you're trying to overwrite `s(1,:)` which is 1 x 128

Comment: Yes, you are right. I change the code `s( 1 , : )  =  mod( s( 1, : ) + k( 1, : ) , 2 ) ;` Thank you very much.